# Easytabs - resizing / repositioning the vertical tab panel container div to the center of the main div

Tags: html, jquery, css

Folks:

I am using the "easytabs" jQuery plugin to come up with vertical tabs along the right edge of the main div that holds all content of the web page.

My knowledge of CSS is poor. I have made good progress but stuck in one last step to achieving my final goal.

I have been trying the last few hours to reposition and resize the panel-container div that holds the vertical tab content divs - div1/div2/div3/div4, but I have not been able to, thus far.

I am trying to see if I can get a little help from experts here on this forum to point out to what is it that I am missing.

I want the panel-container div to be, say, at the center of the page. When I try to give a width to the panel-container div, in pixels, the vertical tabs get messed up.

Also I wanted to see if someone can help me optimize the text orientation and transform properties for the vertical tabs defined in the CSS. I only managed to fix the location of the vertical tabs
by trial and error. I think there must be a cleaner way of doing this.

The vertical tab strip has an offset of about 2 pixels to the left in Firefox, but looks good in Microsoft Edge. How can I fix this?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./easytabs-vert.css" media="all">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../jspkg-archive/vendor/jquery.hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../jspkg-archive/lib/jquery.easytabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#tab-container').easytabs(); 
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body >
    <div style="width:1320px; height:928px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid green">

        <div id="tab-container" class="tab-container" style="float:right; left:1321px">  

            <ul id="vertitab" class='etabs'  style="width:500px;">
                <li class='tab active'><a href="#div1">Requests</a></li>
                <li class='tab'><a href="#div2">Orders</a></li>
                <li class='tab'><a href="#div3">Payments</a></li>
                <li class='tab'><a href="#div4">Parts Lookup</a></li>          
            </ul>      

            <div class="panel-container" style="border: 1px solid blue"> 
                <div id="div1" > Tab 1 Content</div>
                <div id="div2" > Tab 2 Content</div>
                <div id="div3" > Tab 3 Content</div>
                <div id="div4" > Tab 4 Content</div>                
            </div>  

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.etabs { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.tab { 
    display: inline-block; 
    zoom:1; 
    background: #eee; 
    border: solid 1px #999; 
    border-bottom: none; 
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; 
}

.tab a { 
    font-size: 14px; 
    line-height: 2em; 
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px; 
    outline: none; 
}

.tab a:hover { 
    text-decoration: underline; 
}

.tab.active { 
    background: #008000; 
    padding-top: 6px; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 1px; 
    border-color: #666; 
}

.tab a.active { 
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.tab-container .panel-container { 
    background: #fff; 
    border: solid #666 1px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px; 
}

#vertitab {
   position: absolute;

   -webkit-transform-origin: 10% 271%;
      -moz-transform-origin: 10% 271%;
        -o-transform-origin: 10% 271%;
           transform-origin: 10% 271%;

   -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotate(-90deg);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotate(-90deg);
           transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotate(-90deg);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

     -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Here is link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ru03w5Ly/2/

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Are you able to provide a working JS fiddle or codepen demo where we can this issue ?

Comment: I have never done JS Fiddle or codepen before. I will try and find out. Thanks for your time. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/ => just add the code and correct CDN libraries link. I tried to replicate this in a JS fiddle but it did not work. i was not able to see the tabs or anything

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ru03w5Ly/2/        I was able to add the JSFiddle link. But the code is behaving differently from what I see on my machine browser

Comment: Are you sure your browser is using latest version or 
no update is needed.

Comment: On my machine, when I click on a tab, the content div only shows the content for the particular div, say, "Tab 1 Content" when I click on Requests, "Tab 2 Content" when I click on Orders, and so on.

Comment: I dont think it is a browser udpate issue.

Comment: @user765081 You might have added easytab plugin wrong, because when i added it , it worked.https://jsfiddle.net/odp3q07t/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen: Thank you for your time, and help. Now how do I position the div.panel-container at the center of the screen. I tried changing the CSS, but I have not been able to. Can you please help?

Comment: I added the below lines to the CSS for panel-container,  
    position:absolute;
    right:50%;
    top:50%;
and I was able to position the panel-container div to the center of the main div, as I asked in my original question.
@AlwaysHelping / CarstenLøvboAndersen
Thank you both, for taking the time to read through and help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I added the below lines to the CSS for panel-container,

```
position:absolute;
right:50%;
top:50%;
```

and I was able to position the panel-container div to the center of the main div, as I asked in my original question.
@AlwaysHelping , @CarstenLøvboAndersen
Thank you for taking the time to read through and try and help me out.